# Cart coupon code form isn't working after AJAX refresh

Tags: magento-enterprise, cart, ajax

I am working to make the cart to work with AJAX, for update or remove products from the cart, the problem I am facing is that for some strange reason the onclick HTML attribute isn't working after the complete AJAX "reload" of the cart and well I could not find the problem for this, I tried to restore the onclick function and it didn't work.

Here is the HTML code for the form:

```
<form id="discount-coupon-form" action="http://proyecto-c.pengostores.mx/checkout/cart/couponPost/" method="post">
<div class="discount">
    <h2>Código de cupón</h2>
    <div class="discount-form">
        <label for="coupon_code">Código de cupón</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="remove" id="remove-coupone" value="0">
        <div class="field-wrapper">
            <input class="input-text" type="text" id="coupon_code" name="coupon_code" value="">
            <div class="button-wrapper">
                <button type="button" title="Canjear" class="button2" onclick="discountForm.submit(false)" value="Canjear"><span><span>Canjear</span></span></button>
                                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

And the script that instanciate the funciton on the onclick attribute:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var discountForm = new VarienForm('discount-coupon-form');
discountForm.submit = function (isRemove) {
    if (isRemove) {
        $('coupon_code').removeClassName('required-entry');
        $('remove-coupone').value = "1";
    } else {
        $('coupon_code').addClassName('required-entry');
        $('remove-coupone').value = "0";
    }
    return VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(discountForm)();
}
</script>
```

And it looks like the form isn't getting validated or something.
Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Show us your controller action.

Comment: Literally what we return is this checkout.cart block as HTML like this: /**
    * function to get the checkout.cart block as html
    * @return string || null
    */
    protected function _initCart()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $cart = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('checkout.cart');
        if(is_object($cart)){
         return $cart->toHtml();
        }else{
         return null;
        }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After cart reload you should again assign `discountForm` var, because your form is lost and new form is rendered (I assume because don't know, you wrote "complete reload cart"). And then attach submit function again.

```
discountForm = new VarienForm('discount-coupon-form');
discountForm.submit = function (isRemove) {
if (isRemove) {
    $('coupon_code').removeClassName('required-entry');
    $('remove-coupone').value = "1";
} else {
    $('coupon_code').addClassName('required-entry');
    $('remove-coupone').value = "0";
}
return VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(discountForm)();
}
```

Add it to your reload function (ajax callback function?).
Of course don't duplicate the code, first define `var discountForm;` as empty and then extract above snippet as a function and call it on body load and on ajax load.

Comment: Hi @mkutyba thanks for the response, I have tried that solution but it isn't working, I tried making that on the Chrome console and the form worked but not if I make it on the success action of the ajax call, why could be that? Because the var discountForm is in another scope? Thanks again

Comment: I get it working, your answer is in part right but not completely, what I needed to do to make it working was reinit all the javascript that is defined on the <script type="text/javascript"> but the discountForm var without the var before the init. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake, the submit event handler must be reinitialized too.